# Is there any way to automatic detect required modules and packages in my own python project

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I want to create a python distribution package, and need to check all the required packages for my own package.

For **requirements.txt**, it include all the packages it needs. However, I want to find a way to check all the packages I need, and also, for some of the packages, they are also some requirements of other packages in my project.

Is there any way to check which packages I need, and maintain the minimum required packages for my own project?

Comment: I would say use `virtual environment` on you development machine, and then just do `pip freeze`

Comment: I still got a bit confused, would you mind to provide an example or instructions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually people know their requirements by having separate [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) with required modules installed. In this case, it is trivial to make the `requirements.txt` file by running the following while being inside the virtual environment:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Also, to avoid surprises in production and be confident about the code you have, would be good to have tests and a good [test coverage](https://docs.python.org/devguide/coverage.html). In case, there is a module imported but not installed, tests would show it.

---

Another way to find modules that cannot be imported is by using [`pylint`](http://www.pylint.org/) static code analysis tool against the package. There is a special [`F0401 - Unable to import %s`](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages%3af0401) warning.

Demo:

- imagine you have a `test.py` file that has a single `import` statement

  ```
  import pandas
  ```
- `pandas` module is not installed in the current python environment
- here is the output of `pylint test.py`:

  ```
  $ pylint test.py
  No config file found, using default configuration
  ************* Module test
  C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
  F:  1, 0: Unable to import 'pandas' (import-error)
  W:  1, 0: Unused import pandas (unused-import)
  ```

Answer (score 9):

`pip freeze` will print whatever packages happended to be installed in your current envirenment. To list the packages that are actually being imported use `pipreqs`:

```
pip install pipreqs
pipreqs path_to_project
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just keep in mind some packages might get named incorrectly so need to review it (eg. `scikit-image==0.17.2` will become `skimage==0.0`)

Comment: Link to pipreqs: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs